# Does XAML support declaring a non-generic IList collection?

Tags: c#, list, xaml, uwp

I have a collection class that implements `IList` but am struggling to create an instance of it in XAML.

In the code below, if I change `IList` to use the generic version - `IList<object>` - then the code works fine. The implication being that `IList` is, rather strangely, not supported. Is this the case and/or should it be considered a bug?
`ICollection` behaves similarly.

The Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-syntax-guide#collection-syntax) only states that an `Add` method is typically used and does not mention any interfaces. The framework documentation on GitHub [here](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/framework/xaml-services/collections-and-collection-types-for-xaml.md) does specifically say that `IList` is the basis for XAML list concepts - though it's unclear (to me) whether that refers to WPF or UWP (or ...).

MyList.cs:

```
...
namespace Project
{
    public class MyList : IList
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Test.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="Project.Views.Test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Project">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:MyList x:Key="TestList">
                <x:String>Test</x:String>
            </local:MyList>
        </Grid.Resources>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

This causes two errors:

```
1. Missing Content Property definition for Element 'MyList' to receive content 'String'
2. Unknown member '_UnknownContent' on element 'MyList'
```

which suggests that the XAML processor has no idea that `MyList` is a collection.

Comment: Why do you _specifically_ want to use `IList`?

Comment: UWP uses windows runtime APIs, not .NetFramework APIs. It's different from WPF.